# how to rotate sprite in a radius with specific distance

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

hi friends i am implementing cocos2d game. in that i want to rotate a ccsprite with a specific distance in a given radius. i am implementing this. I want to rotate sprite clockwise and after some time anti clockwise. what to make change in that.

```
self.isAccelerometerEnabled = NO;
        TimerFlag = 0;
        float AngleTick = 0.1;
        currentAngle -= AngleTick;
        circleCenter.x = 280;
        circleCenter.y = 160;
        newTankFish.position = ccpAdd(ccpMult(ccpForAngle(currentAngle), 120), circleCenter);
        newTankFish.rotation = currentAngle * -180 / M_PI;
        id tankFishMove  = [CCRepeat actionWithDuration:3.0];
        id TankPowerDone = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(TankPowerOver)];
        [newTankFish runAction:[CCSequence actions:tankFishMove, TankPowerDone, nil]];
        [CoinProjectiles addObject:newTankFish];
```

Comment: do u mean u want to rotate a CCSprite around a point that is not its center ? if so check setAnchor Point then rotate normally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// For Clockwise Rotation

    float AngleTick = 0.1;
    //currentAngle -= AngleTick;
    currentAngle = currentAngle+AngleTick;

    circleCenter.x = 120;
    circleCenter.y = 140;
    CircleSprite.position = ccpAdd(ccpMult(ccpForAngle(currentAngle), 0), circleCenter);
    CircleSprite.rotation = currentAngle * -180 / M_PI;
    id CircleSpriteMove  = [CCRepeat actionWithDuration:0.1];
    [CircleSprite runAction:CircleSpriteMove];

// For Anti Clockwise Rotation
    float AngleTick1 = 0.1;
    currentAngle1 -= AngleTick1;
    //currentAngle = currentAngle+AngleTick;
    circleCenter1.x = 360;
    circleCenter1.y = 180;
    CircleSprite1.position = ccpAdd(ccpMult(ccpForAngle(currentAngle1), 0), circleCenter1);
    CircleSprite1.rotation = currentAngle1 * -180 / M_PI;
    id CircleSpriteMove1  = [CCRepeat actionWithDuration:0.1];
    [CircleSprite1 runAction:CircleSpriteMove1];
```

Comment: Thanks for help i have solve my problem for rotation a sprite clock wise and anti clockwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a sprite (B) as child of another sprite (A) and give B a position of 100,0 and then run the CCRotateBy action on it (360 degrees), you'll see that it does exactly what you want.

This works with any child node of a node, it basically uses the parent as the center point for the rotation, whereas the position determines the rotation's radius.

You do not need to use any of the calculations in the other answer, but of course that'll work. It's just a lot more code.